# How do I write to a file outside of the data directory in android?

Tags: java, android, file

I have a file that I'm writing to in my program currently and it works perfectly fine. What annoys me about how it works right now though, is that it's in the app's directory (e.g.com.appwriter.thisapp) and I'm wondering how to write to a file maybe in the documents folder.

Can anybody show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
```

This function will return the file path string to Internal Storage.

Please let me know if it works, if it doesn't, I will try to help you in another plan ;)

Comment: It runs correctly and it gives me `/storage/emulated/0` for a result but I can't find where that is on the phone.

Comment: @NoahBaxley: That is the root of [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html). If you are viewing your phone's storage via a desktop file manager and a USB cable, the root of external storage frequently gets named "Internal Storage", so you would look there. Note that the approach outlined in this answer may not work on Android Q and higher devices.

Comment: @NoahBaxley /storage/emulated/0 is the location to Internal Storage, where all folders, like 'Android', 'DCIM', 'Pictures', etc... are located. And that location is outside the data path.